# Images logging as 404s with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Due to Zend rewriting URL's to module/controller/action, its reporting that images are coming through as a 404.

Here is the error:

```
  [_requestUri:protected] => /images/Movie/124/thumb/main.png
                [_baseUrl:protected] => 
                [_basePath:protected] => 
                [_pathInfo:protected] => /images/Movie/124/thumb/main.png
                [_params:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [controller] => images
                        [action] => Movie
                        [124] => thumb
                        [module] => default
                    )

                [_rawBody:protected] => 
                [_aliases:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_dispatched:protected] => 1
                [_module:protected] => default
                [_moduleKey:protected] => module
                [_controller:protected] => images
                [_controllerKey:protected] => controller
                [_action:protected] => Movie
                [_actionKey:protected] => action
```

Here is my HTACCESS

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I guess what I need todo is put some sort of image or /design detection so its not routing to index.php

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the .htaccess rewrite rule you have set there is that if it can't find the file, it will send the request to index.php instead. Which means that if your images aren't reachable (not in the public directory) zend_framework will try to handle it. Which it of course can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default directory structure, it should work when you put your images inside the ./public folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changin your htaccess with

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

witch shoudl let images and other stuff go thru.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your images folder inside your public location, and as Arnie mentions you are good to go. The same goes for any additional files you might want to include at any of your views, for example CSS files.

```
/public
   |__ images/
   |__ css/
```

Cheers.
M.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this snippet

```
 <img src="<?=$this->baseUrl('/img/icon_quickstart.png');?>" alt="start" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same .htaccess and setup for a Zend project but am not seeing that behavior.

Just some thoughts that might send you down the right path:

- Case sensitivity in the path?
- Path doesn't actually exist, causing Apache to pass to index.php?
- Apache configuration (globally) or at the VirtualHost level
- Permissions issue? Does main.png at ./public/main.png render when making your request?
- Overlapping route pattern within application.ini?
- Disabling the .htacces for a bit, just to see if it's mapping the directories properly?

Just some ideas.
-andrew